# any conditional causes fatal error

Tags: conditionals, fatal

This is probably only partly related to ee and more to do with server setup but I am hoping someone can help. Adding any conditional to my templates results in the following error:

Fatal error: Call to undefined function EllisLab\ExpressionEngine\Library\Parser\Conditional\ctype_alpha()

This is on a local machine setup which is new. I am running AMPPS I did a phpinfo check and it does say --enable-ctype=shared so I am assuming ctype is installed. I have tried this with the server running both php 5.3.29 and 5.4.32 and both produce the same results.

I have even tried it with a conditional as simple as

```
{if "yes" == "yes"}Do something{/if}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry found the answer here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24867361/problems-with-ampps even though it appears the extension is there apparently it is not and I had to check it off on the extensions page.

Comment: Hi Phil, could you please mark this answer as 'answer'? Thanks!